# Deserializing Json in Console App

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am creating a Web API endpoint that will act as a service to retrieve our application configurations, do logging, etc. The problem I am running into is being able to deserialize the Json in the console applications.

**Setup**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Person")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPerson()
{
    Person person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Steve",
        LastName = "Rogers",
        DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1920, 7, 4)
    };

    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person));
}
```

**Console Application**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");

    var response = client.GetAsync("api/Person").Result;
    var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var person = DeserializeJson<Person>(data);
}

public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string input)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
    var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.ToString());
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result2.ToString());
}
```

**Values**

> data = "\"{\\"FirstName\\":\\"Steve\\",\\"LastName\\":\\"Rogers\\",\\"DateOfBirth\\":\\"1920-07-04T00:00:00\\"}\""
>
> result = "{\"FirstName\":\"Steve\",\"LastName\":\"Rogers\",\"DateOfBirth\":\"1920-07-04T00:00:00\"}"
>
> result2 = {{
>     "FirstName": "Steve",
>     "LastName": "Rogers",
>     "DateOfBirth": "1920-07-04T00:00:00"
>   }}

The issue that I am having is that I cannot deserialize into the `Person` object until I have deserialized for the 3rd time. The value in `result2` is the only one I have been able to successfully deserialize into `Person`. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this deserialization? Preferably without having 3 iterations.

Comment: i think the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person) may be useless in the web API answer and can change the response format, did you try to just return somethings like :  return Ok(person); from you web api endpoint ?

Comment: I tried a return type of `string` as well as using the different `Formatting` overloads of `.SerializeObject()` Still no luck.

Comment: And without using .SerializeObject() ?

Comment: The WebApi serializes it by default.

Comment: Of course, that's why doing JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person) is not necessary :)

Comment: It is necessary so I can add options for when a Web Application uses the end point.

Comment: yeah. you've serialized the serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the following to run successfully (based on [this Microsoft article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)):

**Console App:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3963/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Person");
            Person product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>();
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        Person person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Rogers",
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1920, 7, 4)
        };
        return person;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

1. Add  Newtonsoft.Json to the project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWaFF.png)

2. Add using in your class-> using Newtonsoft.Json;
3. Parse it -> string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);